# Problem indexing tibbles: error in "vec_as_location()"

Tags: r, tidyverse, tibble, rlang

Just doing this,

```
library(tibble)
x <- as_tibble(mtcars)
x[1,1]
```

and getting the following error:

```
Error in `vec_as_location()`:
! `...` must be empty.
x Problematic argument:
* call = call
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
```

I really don't know what's happening here. I've reinstalled tibble, and also tidyverse, and even rlang, but I'm getting the same error again and again. Not when I do `x[1,]`, but I get it again when I do `x[,1]`.

In principle, it is possible to retrieve the first row and column by doing this, isn't it?

Comment: What version do you have of `tibble`?

Comment: @Quinten **3.1.8**, according to `sessionInfo()`

Comment: I cannot reproduce the error with that version (on Windows).

Answer (score 0):

The following worked for me:

1. Start a new R session / restart
2. Install `vctrs`: `install.packages("vctrs")`
3. Install `readr`: `install.packages("readr")`
4. Try your code again